# Toshiba laptop only shows black screen with mouse pointer after starting up

Tags: windows-vista, laptop

When I boot up my laptop, it shows the logo and the status bar.  Then, the screen goes black with movable cursor. I tried <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, but it doesn't work. If I press <kbd>shift</kbd> 5 times, it makes a sound. I already removed the battery and restarted it, but still the same. I can go into safe mode and scanned through there. Still, the desktop won't show up.

i don't know what else to check.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this a new installation of windows, or has it developed this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please associate your Stack Overflow and Super User account at http://stackoverflow.com/users/342287?tab=accounts Thanks and success.

Answer (score 1):

One common cause of this issue is a driver issue with resolutions higher than the base 640x480 you get in safe mode.  This could be either video driver or LCD driver or both.  One thing you can try that worked on my HP laptop with the same problem is to close and re-open the lid.  On my HP this cycled the LCD screen off and back on and this would usually get it to work.  I eventually found that Vista (and later Win7) had misidentified my video card and installed the wrong driver during installation.  Once I had manually installed the correct driver, it never happened again.

Answer (score 0):

What was the last event that occurred in your Windows? Do you remember?
Follow step by step this way.

The First step:

When turn on the device, Change your first boot device priority to your optical drive (CD/DVD ROM). Insert the Windows vista installation disc into the optical drive. 
Your computer try to boot from the Windows Vista installation disc.

The Second Step:
When your system boot up from DVD, Click the 'Repair your computer' option like as picture.

[image: Repair your computer]

The Third Step:

Click the 'Startup Repair' option.

[image: Startup Repair]

The Fourth Step:

Let the startup repair wizard do its thing. When it's finished, it should prompt you to reboot, and then the process is complete!

[image: Startup Window]

The Fifth Step:

If repairs are not successful, you'll see a summary of the problem and links to contact information for support. Your computer manufacturer might include additional assistance information.

I think this way is your answer and
Good Luck