# Laptop not opening..black coloured screen with just mouse cursor moving

Tags: windows-vista, blank-screen

Laptop configuration:

```
32 bit operating system
2038 MB RAM
Windows Vista Home Basic
Intel Core 2 Duo
```

**Problem:**
I am not able to open my laptop...nothing appears, just microsoft logo with loading bars. While choosing to go in safe mode also doesn't help, the same thing happen i.e. blank scree. All it shows is black coloured blank screen with the mouse cursor moving as per my mouse movement. I have read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/141715/toshiba-laptop-only-shows-black-screen-with-mouse-pointer-after-starting-up) that it could be a driver related problem, screen resolution, video card etc. But how to correct that if I am not able to open the computer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you boot from CD using a Windows cd? I suggest (and there might be a simpler solution) using another pc to download the latest gfx drivers for your gfx card and copy them to a flash drive.

I know the following works in XP, I can't remember if Vista had the option though I dont see why not....

When installing XP there's an option to hit 'F6' i think to install 3rd party drivers (look at the bottom of the screen and you'll see the prompt - this is on the initial blue screen when it's loading the setup files) . Use this to point to your gfx drivers on your flash drive. Try this for Vista. It should install your drivers.

The above should work if it is a driver issue. And if it works then you can slipstream the drivers into your windows installation - within legal limits of course.